# How do I create commands in Discord?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord.py, bots

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<', intents=None)

@bot.command()

async def normal(ctx):

    await ctx.send("The normal command")


bot.run("MTA1MjU0ODMzNTY4NjQwMjEwOQ.G0umvR.iElF5nzDjjJcvIvKfZQa0Lfelglh7sXPapuFHc")
```

When I type "<normal" it does not show me any result as if the bot is not working but ERORR does not appear

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8oDV.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY6Vm.png)

What can I do?

Comment: "does not work" is not suffiecient, please add examples of what you tried, what error you get and properly format the code!

Comment: Also, with minimal reseach you would be able to find a solution. Look at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to run a bot. Just add at the end of the code `bot.run("TOKEN")`. Where `"TOKEN"` is a token bot that can be reached [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications) (I think you already know exactly where the button is to get token)

Code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<', intents=None)

@bot.command()
async def normal(ctx):
    await ctx.send("The normal command")

TOKEN = 'OTM4NTgwOTczMDU3MDkzNzAy.GnG96L.afrgSpK7OowwxQkkTnR3Sx9p76rbdRetHIChN0'# This token is not true, it's just a set of random characters 
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: The question already uses `bot.run`. Please make sure to read the question and see the screenshots provided. Thank you.